# simultaneous bilingualism

Tags: language-acquisition, bilingualism

Are there any reliable studies on simultaneous bilingualism effects. What effects does it have on children when they are only learning to read and write in one. More importantly how does it effect their acquisition of the L2?

Comment: What do you mean by "simultaneous bilingualism"?

Comment: Children don't learn to read when they're becoming bilingual. Reading comes later at school if it happens at all. Language (and bilingualism) are entirely **oral**. Writing is technology, not language.

Answer (score 1):

Roy Major, who was a student of David Stampe at Ohio State, did a phonological analysis of Roy's child as it simultaneously learned English and Portuguese.  I think I read a version of his MA thesis, but it was a long time ago.  I know that David thought highly of Roy's work on this.  There is a list of Roy's publications here: [Roy Major vita](https://webapp4.asu.edu/directory/person/86150).